# GitHub for mac not behaving properly with post-commit hook

Tags: github, githooks, github-for-mac, post-commit-hook

I usually use [GitHub for Mac](http://mac.github.com/) to commit code to my GitHub projects because it makes it a bit quicker to do. For my current project, I had to set up the following pre-commit hook:

```
if [ -e images/sprites-01.png ]
then
    mv -f images/sprites-01.png images/sprites.png
    git add images/sprites.png
    git commit --amend -C HEAD --no-verify
fi
```

When I commit through the command-line it simply does the normal commit, and then it executes the hook which amends to the previous commit and I can get my newly renamed file in. When I push, I see everything as a single commit, as if nothing ever happened.

However, if I make my changes and then use GitHub for Mac to sync them, when I sync it says "Please commit all your changes before syncing." and then it shows the `images/sprites-01.png` in the file list as a file that still needs to be deleted, as if it was executing the hook but was ignoring the amended commit.

What can I do to make this work?